# How to efficiently match strings between two big lists with python? (510.000.000 comparisons)

Tags: python, list, comparison, data-science

I am facing the problem of a very long running for loop.

There are two python lists (A and B):

A contains around 170.000 strings with lengths between 1 and 100 characters.
B contains around 3.000 strings with the same length variety.

Now i need to find items from list A which contain one item from list B.

Considering that each string from A needs to be compared with each string from B it results in 510.000.000 comparisons. This seems computational too expensive.

What possibilities are there to speed things up?

Pseudo-code:

```
A = []  # length: 170.000 (strings)
B = []  # length: 3.000 (strings)

for item in A:
    for element in B:
        if element in item:
            print("store the item which contains the element to db")
```

Sample content for some elements of the list:

```
A[0] = "This is some random text in which I want to find words"
A[1] = "It is just some random text"
...
B[0] = "text"
B[1] = "some random text"
...
```

I don't want to stop after the first match as there could be more matches.
The goal is to store all matches in some new variable/db.

Comment: You want this:
`Now i need to find items from list A which contain one item from list B` or the reverse that is represented in your code? `if item (A) in element (B)`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I adapted the code to fit the text now.

Comment: Did you try to add a break if element B is in A? This way you will reduce the execution time

Comment: What can you tell us about the string contents?

Comment: @IoaTzimas there could be multiple matches so cannot break the loop after the first match.

Comment: If element A includes at least on item from B then you don't bother for more, isn't it? Anyway, it would help if you could provide some sample of your lists, so that we will examine some faster solutions

Comment: @IoaTzimas I think "element" means "element", not "item". Question is whether they want elements to be stored to db multiple times (if they match multiple items). If not, then switch the loops and break as you say.

Comment: I updated the question concerning your feedback.
I actually store the item which contains the element. (sorry for the confusion) and i dont mind if i store it multiple times

Comment: You can sort both lists by length of strings and therefore break your inner loop if length of `element` is greater than `item`. It won't make complexity lower but it will decrease number of operations

Comment: @busfighter this sound promising although it is in question how computational expensive the sorting is?

Comment: What exaclty do you want to store in db? The element A or the matced part (equal with item B)?

Comment: sorting has O(n*logn) complexity(which is lower than O(n*m) if n and m are of one order) and finding length of string is cheaper(O(1)) than checking if string is a substring of another one(O(n*m) where n and m are lengths of strings)). So yes that must be faster in average case

Comment: Now you say *"I dont mind if i store it multiple times"*. But do you *want/need* to store it multiple times, or is once enough?

Comment: Are there any characters guaranteed not to be in the strings? Maybe `chr(0)`?

Comment: I really want(!) to store it each time it is found and i want to store the item which contains the element + the element in another column of the database. (It is part of a mapping process.) And i expect every kind of character possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with the solution which @busfighter suggested in the comments:

> "You can **sort both lists by length** of strings and therefore
> **break your inner loop if length of element is greater than item**. It won't make complexity lower but it will decrease number of
> operations."

Speedwise he says:

> "sorting has O(nlogn) complexity(which is lower than O(nm) if n and m
> are of one order) and finding length of string is cheaper(O(1)) than
> checking if string is a substring of another one(O(n*m) where n and m
> are lengths of strings))"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas as well.

```
adf = (
    pandas.DataFrame(A,columns=['text'])
    .assign(strlen=lambda x: x['text'].str.len())
) #create a df from the first array

bdf = (
    pandas.DataFrame(B,columns=['text'])
    .assign(strlen=lambda x: x['text'].str.len())
    .sort_values('strlen')
) #create a df from the second array

resultdf = pandas.DataFrame()

for i,row in bdf.itterrows():
   if len(row['text']) > adf.text.max():
       break
   resultdf = resultdf.append(
           adf[lambda x: x['text'].str.contains(row['text'])],ignore_index=True)

resultdf
```

Comment: but will it be faster than using classical lists and for loops?

Comment: I think pandas filtering works faster than iterating over 170000 array cells. and you will only have 3000 iterations.

Comment: okay sounds like worth a try. @busfighter suggested to sort the lists first and break the loop when the length exceeds the following iterations elements. Could this be implemented here as well?

Comment: To sort which list? and by what? you can easily sort pandas df using .sort_values('column_name',ascending=True or False).

Comment: Busfighter suggested to sort both lists by the item length and once the element length is longer then the item length we can break the loop to save iterations which can't match anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
d={}
for i in range(1,101):
    d[i]=[]
    for x in A:
        for y in range(min(101, len(x))-i+1):
            d[i].append([x[y:y+i]), A])

result=[]
for item in B:
    s=d[len(item)]
    for k in s:
        if item==s[0]:
            result.append(s[1])
```

Explanation: We create a dict with keys 1-100 which represent the possible lengths of elements in B. We loop in lista A. For each item in A, we loop from 1 to max (minimumn from length of item or 100) and save all parts of A to associated key in d.
When this finishes, we only have to loop list B once, and compare the element (of B) with the values in respective key of d.
For example if length of element is 20, we will only check in d[20]. If element is eual with some item, we save the respective A-item

Comment: Interesting approach i will try. Can it be adapted to be more flexible concerning the character length as there might be longer strings in the futher as well.

Comment: How about just a dict mapping substrings of A-strings to their A-strings? Should be faster and avoid duplicate substring objects being held in memory.

Comment: @superb rain it would be a good idea, if there are a lot of duplicates in A, however this has to do with what we will save in database. If we save the entire A item, then it wouldn't help

Comment: Why wouldn't it help? It would remove the *search* over `s`.

Comment: Oh wait, actually... since you're looking up whole elements of B... don't build a structure for A but turn B into a set. And then just check whether the current A-substring is in that set. (Or have multiple sets of B-elements, one for each string-length.)

Answer (score 0):

First answer: if you only need to do it once, just brute force it. 570M substring operations is a lot, yes, I'd guess it will take an hour or so, but that's less time than it will take you to figure out, write, and debug a faster solution.

Second answer: try putting the strings in B into a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  In theory, this will make it faster, but in practice, it probably won't unless you find a python trie library that is implemented in C.  Otherwise, traversing a trie (or really any other string search data structure) in python is going to be slow.

The problem you are facing is that if you have a single string from A and a single string from B, then `b in a` will be relatively fast because under the hood the substring matching will run in C. But if you code up a more theoretically efficient solution in python, even if the "big O" running time is faster, the actual running time will likely be slower because interpreted python is much slower than C.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions (where l1 is the first list and l2 is the second list):

Solution A, Binary search (time complexity O(nlogn)):

```
import bisect
def method_bisect(x, b):
    index = bisect.bisect_left(b, x)
    if x == b[index]:
        return x
    return None


results = []
l2.sort()
for l in l1:
    result = method_bisect(l, l2)
    if result:
        results.append(result)
```

Second solution hash table (time complexity O(n)):

```
B_d = {key: [] for key in l2}
results = []
for l in l1:
    if l in B_d:
        results.append(l)
```

Answer (score -3):

def two_list(a,b):
for item in a:
for num in b:
if item==num:
print(item)

print(two_list(a,b))

Comment: This is plainly wrong. It has the same efficiency as OP's question and is not what the question is about.